# How can I use an autosave partial view on a page with multiple forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

Extending the example found at [Autosave in MVC (ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987034/autosave-in-mvc-asp-net), I wanted to create a partial to reuse in my application. I have one view with a tabbed layout, and each tab has its own form, and this is causing problems, namely that every form tries to submit every time, and only the first timestamp in the document updates. I understand why this is happening, but I don't know how I can fix it.

Partial's cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-lg-2" for=""> </label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <span class="help-block" id="autosaveTime">Not Autosaved</span>
</div>
</div>

@{
    var autosaveString = "'" + @ViewData["autosaveController"] + "'";
    if (ViewData["autosaveAction"] != null && ViewData["autosaveAction"] != "")
        autosaveString += ", '" + ViewData["autosaveAction"] + "'";
} 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        autosave(@Html.Raw(autosaveString));
    });
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
//methodName is optional-- will default to 'autosave'
function autosave(controllerName, methodName)
{
    methodName = typeof methodName !== 'undefined' ? methodName : 'autosave'
    var dirty = false;
    $('input, textarea, select').keypress(function () {
        dirty = true;
    });
    $('input, textarea, select').change(function () {
        dirty = true;
    });
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (dirty == true) {
            var form = $('form');
            var data = form.serialize();
            $.post('/' + controllerName + '/' + methodName, data, function () {
                $('#autosaveTime').text("Autosaved at " + new Date);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                $('#autosaveTime').text("There was a problem autosaving, check your internet connection and login status.");
            });
            dirty = false;
        }
    }, 30000); // 30 seconds
}
```

I have 2 ideas on how to fix it, but not sure which is more maintainable/workable:

1. Give each form an id, and pass that to the partial/autosave function. Add the name to the autosavetime text block for updates, and to determine which form to serialize/submit.
2. Somehow use jquery's `closest` function to find the form where the autosave block was placed, and use that to do what I was doing explicitly with #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make the URL using your Razor helper's Html extension (dynamically piecing URLs like this in JavaScript is unnecessarily risky).  Take that, and stuff it in a data attribute on the tab control like so:

```
<div class="tab autosave" data-action-url='@Html.Action("Action", "Controller")'>
    <form>
        <!-- Insert content here -->
    </form>
</div>
```

Then, you'll want something like this ONCE -- do not include it everywhere, and remove the javascript from your partial completely:

```
$(function() {
    // Execute this only once, or you'll end up with multiple handlers... not good
    $('.autosave').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $form = $this.find('form'),
            dirty = false;

        // Attach event handler to the tab, NOT the elements--more efficient, and it's always properly scoped
        $this.on('change', 'input select textarea', function() {
            dirty = true;
        });

        setInterval(function() {
            if(dirty) {
                // If your form is unobtrusive, you might be able to do something like: $form.trigger('submit'); instead of this ajax
                $.ajax({
                    url : $this.data('action-url'),
                    data : $form.serialize()
                }).success(function() {
                    alert("I'm awesome");
                    dirty = false;
                });
            }
        }, 30 * 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: @pennstatephil, Yep, that's the one I intended.  I wrote this in a web browser, so this is completely untested code (I'd not be surprised at syntax errors).  I just wanted to show the idea.

Comment: Gotcha, just figured I'd make notes for anyone trying the code verbatim like I did