# Autosave Feature in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Can you please let me know how to implement auto save fetaure in asp.net mvc using jquery and ajax. I have a form as shown below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name =
"frmStudentDetails", id = "frmStudentDetails" }))
{

}
```

The above forms having few controls like textbox, dropdown etc. Present logic is that as soon as the user clicks on save button it will go to the controller "Student" and trigger the action "UpdateStudent"

Is it possible to invoke the same controller and action automatically in a period of 1 minute. If so can you please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autosave in MVC (ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987034/autosave-in-mvc-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many approaches to do this. The first one is you can make another Model for a Student-View like StudentViewModel. In which, you inherit the actual Model Class of Student and then add the extra field of searching, traversing, and updating the records that you are required. You must need to add script-tag-handlers to bind the data from your StudentViewModel.

For more dig in deep, you must read how the Dependency Injection and Repository Pattern works in MVC.