# Is there an API/ solution for Auto-saving data of lengthy web forms using MVC architecture (asp.net,c#,jquery,ajax)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, autosave

I am trying to follow this code in my Html code. [Autosave in MVC (ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987034/autosave-in-mvc-asp-net)

```html
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group" data-dirty="false">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "function()", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" data-dirty="false">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "function()", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
        </div>
```

`As form is lengthy enough having 200 plus controls/elements in it.I have tried local storage to store data at client side but local storage is limited to 10 kb size. It seems that I need to store data at server side. I have to do following things with auto-saving data.

1. When user fills in the form, the data should be saved automatically after 30 seconds or so.
2. If browser is closed mistakenly,by opening the page again, data should be there.
3. If the page refreshes again,data should not be lost.
4. I have to keep track of changes that user made on the web forms too.

Please suggest me solutions for these tasks.

Comment: (comment about question formatting) list items should have a proper spacing. Please check.

Comment: 4KB? I thought it was between 5 and 10 MB across modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JQuery/Javascript to

- Save data after a time out
- Detect redirect/refresh
- Detect DOM closures

I am not aware of any existing library or ability in MVC to do this.